# Angular 2 Long Polling

Tags: angular, rxjs, long-integer, polling

I'm trying to implement long polling request based on a specific REST Interface.

Request:

```
GET url/?hash=9014532 HTTP/1.1
```

Response:

```
{
....
    "hash": 88144687,
    "value": 0
}
```

This way the server responds only as soon as the value has changed since the request.

Such a request requires the last known hash value from the previous response as a query string. 
The server delays a response until the hash code is no longer equal to the one provided by the REST client or the configured timeout for a long polling request has expired (30 seconds by default). 
In the case of the timeout expiration the request returns a 304 status code (not modified) with no content.

what I have right now is:

// AppComponent.ts

```
getValue(){
    this.service.getValue().subscribe(
    data=>{
        console.log('Current value: ', data.value);
    },
    error=>{
        console.log('Error: Could not get the value.', error);
    }
    );
}
```

// Service

```
getValue():Observable<Interface>{
    let url = 'http://localhost/url';

    this.http.get(url)
    .map(res=>this.extractresponse)
    .catch(this.handleError)
}

  extractResponse(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
  }

    handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); 
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

This gives me the value from Response which I get when I start the application. But it doesn't really update the variable. I could use a timeout, but I rather follow the advice of the interface and compare the hash.

In this case I would do:

//AppComponent.ts

```
private _hash:number = 0;
private _value: string ;

getValue(){
    this.service.getValue(hash).subscribe(
    data=>{
        this._hash = data.hash;
        this._value = data.value;
    }, 
    error=>{
        console.log('Error: Could not get the value.', error);
    }
    );

}
```

// Service

```
getValue(hash):Observable<Interface>{
    let url = 'http://localhost/url/?hash=' + hash;

    this.http.get(url)
    .map(this.extractResponse)
    .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

now the question is, I assign the new hash to my private variable _hash, show I just use something like "retryWhen" Error or 304 ? 
If I retry and there is no error. How do I know if the variable will be updated again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're getting the response for the first request, but then it doesn't ever update again?

Calling subscribe() is what triggers the http request and once it's done, the observable is complete. It won't execute again unless you call subscribe() again. You can get around that by using a timer as you mentioned, but you don't want to have a delay. I ran into the same problem with long polling, and finally came across the answer: expand().

The description of expand() is hard to understand, it says it calls the projection function recursively. What?? But what actually happens is that each time an internal observable emits a value, the outer observable emits the same value, then calls your projection function which returns a new observable, then adds that new observable to the internal pool. This is exactly what we want with long polling, but it does require you to split up your logic slightly.

```
public pollValues(id: string): Observable<any> {
  let poll = (stateToken: string) => {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'x-state-token': stateToken});
    return this.http.get<any>('https://blahblah/service/' + id, {headers: headers}).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => {
        console.log("Got error, retrying in 10 seconds")
        return errors.pipe(delay(10000))
      }),
      tap(response => console.log("Got response: ", response)),
    );
  };

  return poll('initial-state-token').pipe(
    expand(response => {
      console.log("Expanding with new token " + response.stateToken);
      return poll(response.stateToken);
    })
  );
}
```

As you can see, the Observable is built in two steps. First, a function called "poll" is created that takes a state token and creates a get request with that token. It also adds a retry when there's an error (with a 10 second delay), and logs to the console.

Then it creates the initial request by calling that new function. Now we have an Observable that will make an http request when you subscribe to it. But we want to add the recursive part with expand(). Expand() will pass the existing http Observable to your subscription, and then it will also call the function that says "Expanding with new token". The return value of that function is another Observable. Now you see why we split up our logic.. the new Observable is another http get but with the new state token. Expand() will take that new http get and execute it (assuming you're still subscribed to the outer Observable) and run expand() on that output as well. That's the recursive part.

So this creates a long-polling Observable that has zero delay between requests. It's important that the web service itself provides the delay (which long-polling services do).

Note: this was written for Angular 5 but you can apply the same rxjs logic in Angular 2, if you're still using that. The only difference will be you still need your response.json() step.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the late reply. I will give it a try in the following days!